# Heredoc Param evaluation in Bash

Tags: bash

```
$times=$1
ssh -A vyas@subdom.dom.net <<- EOF
        for i in {1..$times}
        do
                echo 'Iteration' $i
                url='vyas@app'
                echo 'Connecting to' $url
        done
EOF
```

Both echo statements print blanks for the variable name:

> Iteration 
>   Connecting to

```
$times=$1
ssh -A vyas@subdom.dom.net <<- \EOF
        for i in {1..$times}
        do
                echo 'Iteration' $i
                url='vyas@app'
                echo 'Connecting to' $url
        done
EOF
```

Output:

> Iteration {1…}
>   Connecting to vyas@app

I'm executing the above scripts with ./rt.sh  (./rt.sh 5).
How do I get the value of $i to read 1..$times?

Answer (score 3):

The shell performs brace expansion before variable substitution, so the construct `for i in {1..$x}` cannot work as you expect.

Since you want to pass in a variable, you cannot escape the heredoc terminator, so you have to work to protect all the variables you don't want expanded

```
times=$1    # no "$" on the left-hand side!
ssh -A vyas@subdom.dom.net <<- EOF
        for i in \$(seq $times)
        do
                echo Iteration \$i
                url='vyas@app'
                echo 'Connecting to' \$url
        done
EOF
```